# CLucene 2.3.2 trouble in Codeblocks when read directory with Lucene 2.9 index format

Tags: lucene, indexing, runtime-error, codeblocks, clucene

(my) CLucene version is 2.3.3

(client) Lucene files index format is 2.9.1

at this point there is an error:

```
IndexReader* reader = IndexReader::open(index);
```

error: [screenshot](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130413/E54FS2BT.jpg)

tell me how I can get around the current error, incompatible versions of Lucene?

Luke...?

Comment: At this point? Which one?

Comment: IndexReader* reader = IndexReader::open(index);

Comment: I can give you all the source code if you need to